# Cython C++ and std::string

Tags: c++, python, cython

What is the best way of using C++ standard std::string from cython?  The last cython distribution should make it easy anyway, but I wonder why there are wrappers for std::vector and not for std::string...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cython 0.16 [includes wrappers for std::string](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html#c-strings), which can be imported with:

```
from libcpp.string cimport string
```

Comment: Seems that my declaration with Cython 0.16 on OSX are not compliant with Cython 0.17 on Linux, with OSX I get `Cannot convert 'string' to Python object`

Answer (score 8):

Oops, this question has been hanging here for a few days now. At the end I did this:

```
cdef extern from "string" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass string:
        char* c_str()
```

which is not a complete solution but still it does the thing.

Comment: I would add string(char *) also.  That gives you forward and backward to and from python strings.